# Why session is false in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

After success autorization I get array with a information about user:

```
$authdata = array(
   'logged_in' => true,
   'id_user'   => $checked['idUsers'],
   'time_auth' => time(),
   'status'    => $checked['UsersStatus'],
   'type'      => $checked['UsersTypeAccount'],
);
```

Then set this array to session Codeigniter(array `$checked` is not empty, there is a UsersStatus and UsersTypeAccount):

```
$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
```

After do redirect at controller `profile`:

```
redirect('profile');
```

This controllers checks a user session on empty/true:

```
if ($this->session->userdata("session_id") && $this->session->userdata("type") && (($this->session->userdata("status")){
   // Return Success
}
```

**If make var_dump() session:**

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata("type")).'<br>';     // false
var_dump($this->session->userdata("status")).'<br>'; die(); // false
```

I get a false value, why `type` and `status` fields is not true in session?

Edition:

Also I have done:

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata()); die();
```

**Response:**

```
array(5) { ["session_id"]=> string(32) "85d9e0aa1f738c551b4ba649c36f977c" ["ip_address"]=> string(12) "46.32.174.82" ["user_agent"]=> string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36" ["last_activity"]=> int(1416142399) ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" }
```

So, session is created, but without fields status, type

**From tutorial:**

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

**Important:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata()); die(); // Here I get full session array.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some a long attempts to resolve this trouble I had decided:

1. Update Codeigniter to version 2.2
2. After the code had worked:

**Set session:**

```
$this->session->set_userdata($authdata);
```

**Get session:**

```
$type       = $this->session->userdata['type'];
$status     = $this->session->userdata['status'];
$session_id = $this->session->userdata['session_id'];
```

It helped me, maybe someone too